# Software for controling laser machine or alternative to LasrGRBL

Tags: linux

I recently bought a laser machine, a Ortur laser master II. I am actually looking for a software to control it. Usually, people use it with Windows and the Laser GRBL open-source software. For GNU/Linux, it is advised to use a commercial software called Lightburn, which is free for a 30-days trial.

I am looking for an open-source alternative.

Maybe some of you are actually working with this machine and use on open-source alternative to control the Ortur, so I ask.

My system : Void Linux, 5.8.14_1 GNU/Linux kernel.